# Update Group Policy Offline

Tags: windows, group-policy

DC OS - Window Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Client OS - Windows XP, Windows 7.

Is it possible to update Group Policy while the client is offline?

I have several laptops outside the LAN. The users don't have access to internet as well.

Is it possible to update Group Policy through some files which I can send via CD or any mass storage?

Comment: Microsoft provide no mechanism to allow for this.. The only conceivable way I could think of would be to construct a virtual domain controller on a USB key, then they could boot up the virtual domain controller and sync with that, it wouldn't be easy though.

Answer (score 3):

No, regardless of any other options, they would need an Internet connection to do so.

Comment: Right.  Group Policy is applied by a domain controller.  To update Group Policy, you therefore need to connect to a domain controller.  It's not possible, or desirable, to do an offline GPO update.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old thread, but anyway... if someone else looks for this.

You can not update the group policies, but you can change the local registry values that are applied via the group policies (admin/system permissions required). Restarting the PC will reapply the values/policies.

List of the policies can be found at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25250

There different versions, but the above might be enough im most cases.

p.s. I am looking for option to reapply the policies while offline (this excludes gpupdate as it fails while offline), but also without reboot and logout/login.